# Angular spread operator issue with override environment

Tags: angular

I've environment files in Angular used to change urls depending on environment (dev, staging, production).
This is how it looks like:

environment.common.ts

```
export const commonEnv = {
  myAPI: {
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
      tests: '/tests'
    }
};
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  type: 'loc',
  service: {
    ...commonEnv
  }
};
```

environment.dev.ts

```
export const environment = {
  type: 'dev',
  service: {
    myAPI: {
      baseUrl: 'https://myapi.com',
      tests: '/tests' -> I won't to duplicate it in each env file, because it does not change, it's
    }
  }
};
```

The issue is: I'd like to override baseUrl in each env file and do not need to repeat "tests" field in each env file.

I tried to add "tests" field in each env file, but it's not the solution, because I'm duplicating the code from common.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

One solution to avoid duplicating the "tests" field in each environment file is to use an environment variable for it. You can define the "tests" field in the common environment file as an environment variable, and then access it in each environment file.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to use an environment variable for the "tests" field:

environment.common.ts

export const commonEnv = {
myAPI: {
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
tests: `${process.env.TESTS_URL}`
}
};

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  type: 'loc',
  service: {
    ...commonEnv
  }
};
```

environment.dev.ts

process.env.TESTS_URL = '/tests';

```
enter code here
```

In this example, you define an environment variable called "TESTS_URL" in the dev environment file, and then access this variable in the common environment file using the `${process.env.TESTS_URL}` syntax. This way, you can avoid duplicating the "tests" field in each environment file and still use it in all environments.

Note that you will need to set the "TESTS_URL" environment variable appropriately in each environment file where you want to use it.

Comment: "Note that you will need to set the "TESTS_URL" environment variable appropriately in each environment file where you want to use it." -> I want to avoid it.

Comment: Most or all of your six answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid using an environment variable for the `tests` field and still avoid repeating it in each environment file, you can create a separate configuration file that contains the common configuration options and import it in each environment file.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

1. Create a new file called `config.ts` (or any other suitable name) in your project's root directory, and define the common configuration options in it, including the `tests` field:

   typescript
   export const config = {
   myAPI: {
   baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
   tests: '/tests'
   }
   };
2. In each environment file, import the `config` object from the `config.ts` file, and override the `baseUrl` property as needed:

   typescript
   import { config } from './config';

   export const environment = {
   type: 'dev',
   service: {
   myAPI: {
   baseUrl: 'https://myapi.com',
   ...config.myAPI // Include the common configuration options
   }
   }
   };

This way, you only need to define the `tests` field once in the `config.ts` file, and you can override the `baseUrl` property as needed in each environment file. The `...config.myAPI` syntax is used to include all the other common configuration options defined in the `config.ts` file.

Comment: It doesn't work, throws:
"baseUrl' is specified more than once, so this usage will be overwritten. "

Comment: Most or all of your six answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.